# '%s' % myobject: overloading

Tags: python, string, format

As you know Python supports string formatting, but I want to speak about how it was realised in Python 2. If we type `a=u'абв'; b='abc'; c='%s%s'`, then `c` variable will have a unicode type, so formatting returns unicode object. Is it possible for me to have my own class `myobject`, where variable `c` will have `myobject` type? In other words, can I overload this operator? The answer must work on Python 3 and Python 2, but it was more simple to describe what I want with Python 2. Thanks!

```
class ustream(object):
  '''ustream class provides an easy access for basic operations with Unicode
  streams. The main advantage of this class is that it already has built-in
  support for regular expressions and transliteration.'''
  __slots__ = ['_stream_', 'array', 'stream']

  def __init__(self, stream='', encoding=ENCODING['default']):
    '''ustream.__init__([stream[, encoding]]) -> ustream'''
    if isinstance(encoding, bstream):
      encoding = encoding.stream
    elif isinstance(encoding, ustream):
      encoding = encoding.stream
    if isinstance(stream, bytes):
      stream = stream.decode(encoding)
    elif isinstance(stream, string):
      stream = string(stream)
    elif isinstance(stream, bstream):
      stream = stream.stream.decode(encoding)
    elif isinstance(stream, ustream):
      stream = stream.stream
    else: # if unknown type
      typename = type(stream).__name__
      raise(TypeError('stream must be bytes or string, not %s' % typename))
    self._stream_ = stream

  @property
  def array(self):
    '''unicode stream as array'''
    return([ord(char) for char in self.stream])

  @property
  def stream(self):
    '''unicode stream as string'''
    return(self._stream_)

  def __mod__(self, stream):
    '''ustream.__mod__(stream) <==> ustream % stream'''
    result = self.stream % ustream(stream).stream
    result = ustream(result)
    return(result)

  def __rmod__(self, stream):
    '''ustream.__rmod__(stream) <==> stream % ustream'''
    stream = ustream(stream)
    stream = stream.stream
    result = stream % self.stream
    result = ustream(result)
    return(result)
```

This is a code sample from my laptop. `string` == `str` for Python 3 and `unicode` for Python 2. Just backward compatibility.

Here is what I want to get.

```
>>> src = ustream('a stream')
>>> add = 'Hello man'
>>> result = '%s! Look here: we have %s!' % (add, src)
>>> type(result)
utstream
>>> print(result)
Hello man! Look here: we have a stream!
```

Comment: The `c` variable you have there, in Python 2, would not have a unicode type. It would have a `<type 'str'>`. If you create a *new* variable by interpolating a unicode object into `c`, like `x=c % ("foo", u"bar")` then `x` would have a unicode type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly clear on what you mean, but you can define [`__mod__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__)  (or `__rmod__`) to allow a class to overload the `%` operator...

---

In response to your edit, when I run your code:

```
a = stream('%s')
b = a % ('foo')
print (type(b)) #<class '__main__.stream'>
```

It works just fine.  What's the problem?

---

(and since the above code was edited again), here's the original code I tested:

```
class stream(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, unicode):
      self.data = data
    elif isinstance(data, bytes):
      self.data =data.decode('UTF-8')
    else:
      raise TypeError('invalid data')
  def __mod__(self, data):
    data = stream(data).data
    result = self.data.__mod__(data)
    result = stream(result)
    return(result)
```

---

The reason you can't get what you want is because when python goes to resolve an operator (any operator), it looks at the object on the left of the operator and asks "Does this object provide a suitable implementation for that operator?".  If the answer is yes, then python calls that implementation and returns the result.  If the answer is no, it looks at the object on the right side of the operator and asks the same question.  If the answer is yes, it calls the right object's implementation and returns the result.  If the answer is no, it raises an exception.

Now in your desired output, you have `"this is a string"%( obj1, streamobject )`.  However, when python looks at that expression, it sees a *string* on the left hand side which has a defined `__mod__`, so python will always call that method instead of your user defined methods.  As I said in my comments, the only way to get your object to take precedence is to switch the order (Your object goes before the string).  I can see why you wouldn't want to do this (it's difficult to format more than one item this way).  You'd have to write it as:

```
myobj % ( "this is the format string %o %d %d %d", 1, 2, 3 )  #yuck
```

or similar where `%o` will get replaced by 'myobj.data' somehow.  Ultimately, this is getting really messy and I think it's worth asking *why do you want to do this?*.  (you could provide a convenience function to do all of this really easily).

My final comment on the subject is that you might want to look into overriding a [template](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) for string formatting.  It's not used very often, but may be of use here ...

Comment: Not exactly.  OP has `c = '%s%s'` which does no string formatting or interpolation at all (It just creates a string which *might* be interpolated later).  As far as I know, `__format__` exists to allow users to override how an object's data is transformed into a string when formatting...  What OP is asking about doesn't look like string formatting at all to me ... (but that's why I prefaced my answer by "I'm not exactly clear on what you mean").

Comment: Basically I'm answering the question "In other words, can I overload this operator" assuming that the operator in question is `%`.

Comment: I've already tried it `__mod__` and `__rmod__`. That doesn't work.

Comment: @ghostmansd -- Please post your attempt then and we might be able to help.  I suspect that you're doing something like `'string'%myobject` and you're getting an error.  That error is happening because `__mod__` on the string object takes precedence to `__mod__` on your object.  It could probably work if you switched it around:  `myobject%'string'` -- now `myobject.__mod__` will be called.

Comment: sorry guys, I'm writing from phone, so I have ugly markup. Wait a bit, I'll fix it.

Comment: @ghostmansd -- I edited for you.  (I have a keyboard at my disposal :)

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks, I've edited it again with a more clear from my laptop. :-)

Comment: @ghostmansd -- Now can you put a simple test which shows how your implementation of `__mod__` fails?

Comment: @mgilson: I've showed what I want. I guess it is string formatting, not `__mod__`.

Comment: @mgilson: as you know we have some operators which allow to work with the left argument (they usually start from `__r*`). I'm pretty sure it is possible to make something similar with `"this is a string"%( obj1, streamobject)` and to get `myobject` instance.

Comment: @ghostmansd -- what I'm trying to say is that **`__rmod__` will not be used if the left object provides `__mod__`** (which strings do).  Even if that weren't the case, with the code that you wrote, the right object is a `tuple` which contains an instance of `stream`.  As far as I know, `tuple` objects don't define `__rmod__`, and they certainly won't use the `__rmod__` that is defined on your `stream` class...  (sorry for the bold text -- I just wanted it to stand out since that is the most important thing to understand here).

Comment: I guess that I can just use `myobject("this is a string"%(obj1, streamobject))`, but it's not beautiful. It is really strange that language doesn't hadles such situations.

Comment: @ghostmansd -- you could probably also do something like `myobject("this is a string") % (obj1, streamobject)`.  I really don't think it's that strange.  If you have two objects, one implementing `__mod__` and the other implementing `__rmod__`, the language needs to choose which method to run (or run both).  In any case, the decision is a bit arbitrary -- Python chooses the method on the left object (`__mod__`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement [`__format__`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: could you give an example, please? `myobject` can already successfully be created from `str` by typing `myobject('any string')`.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I misunderstood you. The way @mgilson pointed out should be the correct one.